# windsor component for is  not working as transient

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, transient

We are using windsor  to register a instance for the `IUnitOfWork`interface. `UnitOfWorkContainer.Current` is a static method which returns an instance of IUnitOfWork.

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>()
            .Instance(UnitOfWorkContainer.Current)
                .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

The problem is `UnitOfWorkContainer.Current` is called only ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: You're doing it wrong]

You are giving Windsor a pre-existing instance. Hence it is not creating it - it's reusing the instance you've given it.

In other words, your code could be rewritten to the equivalent:

```
var theOneAndOnly = UnitOfWorkContainer.Current;
 container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>()
            .Instance(theOneAndOnly)
                .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

I think what you really meant was:

```
 container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => UnitOfWorkContainer.Current)
                .LifeStyle.Transient);
```